# Como pegar dados de um text exibido no dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Estou utilizando esta biblioteca para a exibição de dialogs no meu aplicativo:
https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog

Com esta biblioteca é possível exibir no dialog um layout criado, mas não estou conseguindo capturar a entrada do usuário no método setPositiveButton.

```
mMaterialDialog = new MaterialDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyAlertDialog ) )
        .setTitle("Novo Registro")

        .setPositiveButton("Novo", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // PEGAR DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FRAGMENT EXIBIDO AQUI
            }
        })

        .setNegativeButton("Voltar", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMaterialDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_classroom, null);
        mMaterialDialog.setView(view).show();
        //mMaterialDialog.show();
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz quanto a isto ou sugerir uma abordagem mais adequada?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu *fragment* você já "inflou" e está definido, basta então você buscar e definir os elementos através dos *IDs*, e na ação do botão positivo buscar seus valores:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_classroom, null);

final EditText etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);

mMaterialDialog = new MaterialDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyAlertDialog ) )
    .setTitle("Novo Registro")
    .setPositiveButton("Novo", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String foo = etFoo.getText().toString();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Voltar", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMaterialDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

mMaterialDialog.setView(view).show();
```

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou direitinho aqui =)

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
private LayoutInflater inflat;
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

 inflat = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = inflat.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_erro, null);
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setView(layout);
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            Button enviar_erro = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.enviar_erro);
            final EditText obs_erro = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.obs_erro);
            enviar_erro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(obs_erro.getText().toString())) {
                        //pegar texto e enviar obs_erro.getText().toString();
                    } else {
                        obs_erro.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.campo_obrigatorio));
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Layout dialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/obs_erro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape_border_gray"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/descrever_erro"
    android:singleLine="false" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enviar_erro"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/enviar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/verde"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```